# Issues with http redirect

Tags: grails, redirect, tomcat7, context.xml, server.xml

I am using a grails 2.3.7 and am facing issues using redirect in controllers

I had my code running and everything was working properly. The problem started when I deployed my code onto production environment.

For production release I modified the server.xml in tomcat something like this

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" address="myapp.usa.com"               redirectPort="8443" />
```

I added a context inside the default  tag something like this

```
<Context path="" docBase="myapp">
        <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
        <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

When I deployed my application as a war file, it deploys correctly and the index page opens up when I try to access http://myapp.usa.com:8080

However wherever I have used redirect within controllers the code breaks

for example, consider that my code was initially pointing to 
    http://myapp.usa.com:8080/mycontroller/foo
and within this action I issued a redirect to 
    http://myapp.usa.com:8080/mycontroller/boo
I will be redirected to 
    http://myapp.usa.com:8080/mycontroller/myapp.usa.com:8080/mycontroller/boo

Any idea where I am going wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `grails.serverURL` in your application for production, and also include an example of the redirect that is having this issue in your question (e.g. the code from your controller that issues the `redirect`)

Comment: Hi Joshua, My serverURL is "myapp.usa.com:8080" and an example of redirect is something like this                                        def index(Integer max) {
  redirect(action: "importFromExcel")
 }

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you remove the <Context/> and try to deploy as ROOT.war instead?

Comment: Shuoldn't `serverURL` be `http://myapp.usa.com:8080`?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I think even myapp.usa.com:8080 should work, considering that I am using chrome browser. It automatically prepends http://